# Wordpress script before <!DOCTYPE html>

Tags: wordpress, referrer, malware

document.referrer before  in my wordpress site? I understand, that its malware threat, but I can not fix it, please can anybody help me to gain success in this work. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Have you gone through your plugin and theme files? Usually something like that will be placed in your themes header.php or index.php file - but without seeing the exact code, that's just a guess.